# RoR UI for Readonly Emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, user-interface, email

I am build a application to pull incoming emails from a mailbox and display them in read_only mode to users. Users should NOT compose any emails but just readonly access to email list and email content. It should support both text and rich text html emails as well as attachments.

Can you please advise me how to go about this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try taking a look at the [Mailman](http://github.com/titanous/mailman) project by [Jonathan Rudenberg](http://twitter.com/titanous). You should be able to create a simple Rack application within a Rails application for storing the emails in active record models, then create a simple view / controller for displaying them.

Comment: I am more interested in the UI layer to display the email content, list, attachment regardless of email type (plain text or rich email). So, wondering about a component. I looked into roundcube but it is overkill for me as I just need to list and display emails content.

Comment: Just use a standard master / detail set of views. If you wanted, you could add threading. Take a look at any of the web-based email clients to see examples.